# Removing an integer from an id

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have an id:

```
div id ="untitled-region-5"
```

I want to grab that id and remove 4 from it and then do some code with the new id.

So far I am trying something like this from reading about how to perform this:

```
var n = $(this).attr('id').match(/untitled-region-(\d+)/)[1];
```

But I don't know how to remove 4 from the integer.

Comment: You mean subtract 4? i.e. `n - 4`? You could also `parseInt()` the string first, but JavaScript is weakly typed and will usually just sort that out for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var id = $("div").attr("id");
var n = parseInt(id.substring(id.lastIndexOf("-") + 1), 10);
```

I made a jsFiddle too: http://jsfiddle.net/YEWQQ/

Comment: I need to subtract 4 from it though, please see my jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/848Qy/2/

Edit: - I see what I did wrong, nevertheless it still does not work, please see my jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/848Qy/1/

Comment: If you use jQuery, don't use "getElementById" use $("#MY_ID") instead!. By the way, what do you mean with "substract 4" ?

Comment: Because the id of the radio is untitled-region-1 and the id which should match to enable the show/hide is untitled-region-5. so to make them match I need to minus 4 from untitled-region-5. Please see my code and you may understand more what I mean, for some reason it doesn't work.

Comment: An up-to-date jsFiddle using your code, for some reason I gave the wrong link earlier: http://jsfiddle.net/848Qy/3/

Comment: Perhaps, I'm just trying to edit old code which used a very similar technique and worked. Any idea how to go about this?

Comment: Check this http://jsfiddle.net/848Qy/5/
I think that this is what you're trying to achieve. Take some time to see the code.

Comment: Excellent, it works, in regards to the score not working you're missing a bracket }. Brilliant, this is what I want, now to test it vigorously :D

Answer (score 4):

It's still a string, that's why you can't easily use it in math. Some operations work, because they will implicitly convert the value to a number.

Use `parseInt` to explicitly do the conversion, so that you know what you have:

```
var n = parseInt($(this).attr('id').match(/\d+$/)[0]);
n -= 4;
```

Comment: Agreed, but you can use it in math as-is: `alert("untitled-region-5".match(/untitled-region-(\d+)/)[1] - 4);` works fine for me.

Comment: @JohnVasiliou: You can't name variables with hyphens, i.e., `untitled-region`.  You should use an underscore instead.

Comment: @JohnVasiliou: Some errors: You don't need the first line in the function, as the second does the same. You can't use `untitled-region` as variable name, as the dash is used as the subtraction operator.

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/848Qy/1/ yep, doesn't work. Problem is my CMS is making those id's thats why I need a script that will minus 4 from the last integer so it works with another radio button, otherwise I wouldn't have this problem :(

Comment: In between the dashes of untitled-region- can I not use untitled/-/region/-/ or something so that the compiler is aware I am using a dash and not a subtraction operator?

Comment: @JohnVasiliou: You don't have to name your variables the same as the id of the element.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id ="untitled-region-5">​
```

just take n and subtract 4

```
var n = $('div').attr('id').match(/untitled-region-(\d+)/)[1];
var newNumber = n-4;
$('div').attr('id','untitled-region-'+newNumber);
```